# Firebase functions: failed to create function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Following the Firebase examples to create and deploy a function, I keep failing at the deploy phase.
The error, with --debug enabled, shows:

> <<< [apiv2][body] POST
> https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/actus-poc2/locations/us-central1/functions
> {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Cloud Functions uses Artifact Registry
> to store function docker images. Artifact Registry API is not enabled
> in your project. To enable the API, visit
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/artifactregistry.googleapis.com/overview?project=...

Now I was expecting to be able to stay within the confines of the firebase console but this message seems to imply I need to open the Google Cloud Console to enable additional permissions.
Should the code samples better document this?
Or is this a recent change in firebase functions that breaks many of the existing examples?

Comment: Could you share the documentation you were following?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am following this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: Hello, Reuben! It's a good practice here at Stack Overflow that if mine or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to open the Google Cloud Console to enable additional permissions.

The reason why you need to use the Google Cloud Console is because Cloud Functions for Firebase relies on some Google Cloud services. [See](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#why-billing).

Function deployments with Firebase CLI 11.2.0 and higher rely on Cloud Build and Artifact Registry.

> is this a recent change in firebase functions that breaks many of the existing examples?

Deployments to older versions also do rely on some Google Cloud services. Deployments to older versions use Cloud Build in the same way, but rely on Container Registry and Cloud Storage for storage instead of Artifact Registry.

> Should the code samples better document this?

If you do think an update to said documentation could be helpful, here is [more about opening Feature requests](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).